# Merge opening hours in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am looping some opening hours from my DB and I have been able to merge the timestamps into an array based on 7 days of the week e.g.

```
array(7) {
  [1]=>
  string(28) "12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 23:30"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [5]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [7]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
}
```

I wonder how I can merge the array above into an array like this:

```
array(2) {
  ['Mon']=>
  string(28) "12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 23:30"
  ['Tue - Sun']=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
}
```

My conflict is when i sometimes have opening hours like this:

```
array(7) {
  [1]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [2]=>
  string(28) "12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 20:00"
  [3]=>
  string(28) "12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 20:00"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [5]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "-" // Means closed
}
```

And the outcome should be like this:

```
array(2) {
  ['Mon']=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ['Tue & Wed']=>
  string(28) "12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 20:00"
  ['Thu - Sat']=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ['Sun']=>
  string(6) "Closed"
}
```

This is my function so far:

```
function mergeOpeningHours($arr) {

    $days = array();

    $day_name = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');

    // Firstly we merge the days timestamps
    foreach ($arr as $day => $data) {

        if (isset($days[$data['day']])) {
            // then the day has already been defined and we procedd by applying the days following timestamps
            $days[$data['day']] .= ', ' . $data['open'] . ' - ' . $data['close'];
        } else {
            $days[$data['day']] = $data['open'] . ' - ' . $data['close'];
        }

    }

    $final_days = array();

    $d = 1;
    $dd = $days[$d];

    for ($i=1; $i < 7; $i++) { 

        if ($days[$d+1] == $dd) {

            $final_days[$day_name[$d] . ' - ' . $day_name[$d + 1]] = $dd;

        } else {

            $dd = $days[$i+1];

        }

        $d++;

    }


}
```

Which came out with something like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["Wed - Thu"]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ["Thu - Fri"]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ["Fri - Sat"]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ["Sat - Sun"]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ["Sun - "]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
}
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated - thanks!

** SOLUTION **

Thanks to a lot of help from Stackoverflow community I have managed to get together the function needed.

```
function mergeOpeningHours($arr) {

    $days = array();

    // Firstly we merge the days timestamps
    foreach ($arr as $day => $data) {

        if (isset($days[$data['day']])) {
            // then the day has already been defined and we procedd by applying the days following timestamps
            $days[$data['day']] .= ', ' . $data['open'] . ' - ' . $data['close'];
        } else if (empty($data['open']) || empty($data['close']) || $data['open'] == NULL || $data['close'] == NULL) {

            $days[$data['day']] = '-';

        } else {
            $days[$data['day']] = $data['open'] . ' - ' . $data['close'];
        }

    }

    $week = array (1 => 'Mon', 2 => 'Tue', 3 => 'Wed', 4 => 'Thu', 5 => 'Fri', 6 => 'Sat', 7 => 'Sun');
    $newarray = $finalarray = $valArray = array();

    $i = $e = 0;
    foreach ($days as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($newarray[$e][$val]) && count($newarray[$e][$val]) > 0 && ((int)$key - 1 == end($newarray[$e][$val]))) {
            $newarray[$e][$val][$i] = $key;
            $i++;
        } else {

            $e++;
            $i = 0;
            $newarray[$e][$val][$i] = $key;
            $i++;

        }
    }

    foreach ($newarray as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $nk => $nv) {
            $cnt = count($nv);
            if ($cnt > 2) {     
                $finalarray[$week[array_shift($nv)].' - '.$week[array_pop($nv)]] = $nk;
            } elseif ($cnt == 2) {
                $finalarray[$week[array_shift($nv)].' & '.$week[array_pop($nv)]] = $nk;
            } else {
                $finalarray[$week[$nv[0]]] = $nk;
            } 
        }   
    }


    return $finalarray;

}
```

It can take an array like this:

```
array(9) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "23:30"
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "14:00"
}
[2]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "14:00"
}
[3]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "23:30"
}
[4]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "23:30"
}
[5]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "12:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "23:30"
}
[6]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["open"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["close"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
[7]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "16:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "20:00"
}
[8]=>
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "9"
  ["day"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["open"]=>
  string(5) "16:00"
  ["close"]=>
  string(5) "20:00"
}
}
```

and turn it into this:

```
array(4) {
  ["Mon"]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ["Tue & Wed"]=>
  string(28) "12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 20:00"
  ["Thu - Sat"]=>
  string(13) "12:00 - 23:30"
  ["Sun"]=>
  string(1) "-"
}
```

Thanks for all the help and support..

Comment: I will update the question, but mainly I don't have enough PHP knowledge to find a logic solution for this. My way mostly based on a for loop where I looked up all the values and tried to pair them together, but a lot of errors happened, and I couldn't get the puzzle to work properly.

Comment: Also how do you define which days are to which times?

Comment: I have made it so the first array you see is the seven days of the week. 1 = monday and so on.

Comment: @Rizier123 1=Monday, 7= Sunday I assume?

Comment: @Loko Yes.. correct.. :)

Comment: @Dimser I am actually trying to do this right now. I have made it that all the days that have the same times and are coming after eachother, are split up but i cant seem to merge them.

Comment: @Loko v2solutions.com has written an answer where he turns around the key and values and merges them like so.. Maybe it can be helpful? His answer is not 100% correct since we miss a little adjustment, but I working on it as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$week = array (1 => 'Mon', 2=> 'Tue', ....);
$newarray = $finalarray = $valArray = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (count($newarray[$val]) > 0 && ((int)$key - 1 == end($newarray[$val]))) {
        $newarray[$i][] = $key;
        $valArray[$i] = $val;
        $i = $i +1;
    }   
}

foreach ($newarray as $k => $v) {
    $cnt = count($v);
    if ($cnt > 2) {     
        $finalarray[$week[array_shift($v)].' - '.$week[array_pop($v)]] = $valArray[$k];
    } elseif ($cnt == 2) {
        $finalarray[$week[array_shift($v)].' & '.$week[array_pop($v)]] = $valArray[$k];
    } else {
        $finalarray[$week[$v[0]]] = $valArray[$k];
    }    
}
```

Comment: That was quite clever actually to use the data as the keys instead.. It makes a lot of sense.. I just tried this on the more complex version and it came out as "mon - Sat" => 12:00 - 23:30 and "Tue & Wed" => 12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 20:00.. I need to modify it a little so monday doesn't go all the way to saturday in case there are days in between that are different.

Comment: The first foreach loop - doesn't it need an else statement? I get an "undefined index" error. And it seems like the foreach if statement should have an else statement assigning the first value as well.

Comment: May be. I haven't tested the code. Try with else if it removes your error else not required

Answer (score 0):

I got to this:

```
$array=array("
12:00 - 14:00, 16:00 - 23:30",
"12:00 - 23:30",
"12:00 - 23:30",
"12:00 - 23:30"
,"12:00 - 23:30"
,"12:00 - 23:30"
,"12:00 - 23:30"
,"12:00 - 14:00"

);
$days=array(0=>'Mon',1=>'Tuesday',2=>'Wed',3=>'Thu',4=>'Fri',5=>'Sat',6=>'Sun');
//var_dump($array);
//var_dump($days);
$previousvalue=0;
    for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
        if($i!=0){
            if($array[$i]==$previousvalue){
                echo $days[$i].'=>'.$array[$i].'<br>';
            }else{

            }
        }
        $previousvalue=$array[$i];
    }
```

This code will only echo the days that have the same times as the previous ones. So I basically split the other days up with the days that are connected with eachother by being consecutive and having the same time. This might be helpful. Now all I/you need is to get the days that have the same values to merge as: **First day of the consecutives - Last day of the consecutives**. I will edit as soon as I find something.

**NOTE:**

My code starts at index 0 and yours starts at 1